# Frame/edge of Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying different things on a plot, just to practice and learn.
Right now I'm trying to plot with a simple edge and white background. I tried a various things but nothing worked. Last try was to play with "spines" like in the code. The image I got is below.

'

```
fig = plt.figure(facecolor=None, edgecolor='red', figsize=(20, 10))
# x-axis: date
ax = fig.add_subplot()
plt.title('Daily freeCodeCamp Forum Page Views 5/2016-12/2019')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(8))
# y-axis: page views
plt.ylabel('Page Views')
# line-plot y vs x
ax.spines[:].visible = True
ax.spines[:].linewidth = 2
ax.spines[:].edgecolor = 'back'
# line-plot y vs x
ax.plot(df_filtered.sort_index().index, df_filtered.sort_index().value, '#DC143C')
```

'

[image: Line plot with out frame neither white background]

Appreciate some ideas!

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: You shared the output you got, but you didn't say what you actually expected - please describe what you expected or wanted to be different about the presented output.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the ans/question.
I want a line around the plot area (frame without labels, title, etc) and another one around the whole plot (with label and title in it). The idea is to delimiter the plot.
The background color = white already solved with facecolor parameter of the subplot.

Comment: “Back” is not a color

Answer (score 1):

You can set the edgecolors and line width of the figure and axes patch:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.patch.set(lw=2, ec='b')
fig.patch.set(lw=5, ec='r')
```

[image]

Comment: Great! So 'patch' is the feature. Thank you very much!!!